# Postgresql merge columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a main table which is like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS people 
(
    country text,
    full_name text,
    last_name text,
    children_names text[]
);

INSERT INTO people (country, full_name, last_name, children_names) 
VALUES ('de', 'han', 'post', '{"joe", "joe1", "joe2", "joe3"}');
```

I can merge `full_name` and `last_name` like this

```
SELECT
    full_name || '_' || last_name AS obid
FROM 
    people;
```

but I couldn't do the same thing with the `children_names` column I want to select children like this

```
select children_names 
from people;
```

but I want to add last_name filed at the end of each child like this

```
{joe_han,joe1_han,joe2_han,joe3_han}
```

Comment: better to hold the children names row-wise manner within another table along with creating foreign-primary key relationship among this current table in order to obey normalisation rules for the sake of the DB design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a scalar subquery:

```sql
SELECT
  full_name||'_'||last_name obid, 
  (select array_agg(u||'_'||full_name) from unnest(children_names) u) children
FROM people;
```

Yet it would be *much* better to structure your data as @BarbarosÖzhan suggests.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `unnest` function to extract data and then add **last_name** column. After merging data you have to use aggregate to create an array.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e6c8ea38ae8af5a97fc54109807cdd24)

```sql
SELECT
    full_name || '_' || last_name as obid,
    array_agg(value || '_' || last_name)
FROM people CROSS JOIN unnest(children_names) value
GROUP BY 1;
```

Comment: This may be faster than a join, I can't test as I don't have a pg system right now: `SELECT ARRAY(SELECT cn || '_' || last_name FROM UNNEST(children_names) cn) FROM people;`